# Find MAX value of `define in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to create a `define constant that is assigned to one of multiple other`define constants that has the largest value. Something like:

```
`define MAXWIDTH $MAX(`WIDTH0,`WIDTH1,`WIDTH2)
```

Is this possible in Verilog/SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on exactly what you need, there are a few ways to do it (there is no builtin call for maximum like in other languages):

---

#### You have some vectors and you need to get the maximum width for a new vector

```
$bits(v1 + v2 + v3 ...)
```

Use the language to your advantage, noting that the addition of vectors results in a vector that has the maximum width of all the operand vector widths and use `$bits` to get that size. Example:

```
logic [1:0] x;
logic [7:0] y;
logic [10:6] z;
...
max = $bits(x + y + z); // Result: max = 8
```

---

#### You have a few numbers of which you need the maximum

If you put your numbers in an array or queue, you can use the `max` method to get the largest:

```
int x[] = '{n1, n2, n3, ...};
...
max = x.max;
```

Note that this approach has the downside that it cannot be used at compile time for getting the maximum size. Example:

```
int _nums[] = '{13, 2, 17, 8, -1};
...
max = _nums.max; // Result: max = 17
```

---

#### Basically any other time

You'll just have to use the conditional operator, either in a macro or using `let`:

```
`define max2(v1, v2) ((v1) > (v2) ? (v1) : (v2))
`define max3(v1, v2, v3) `max2((v1), `max2((v2), (v3)))
```

OR

```
let max2(v1, v2) = (v1 > v2) ? v1 : v2;
let max3(v1, v2, v3) = max2(v1, max2(v2, v3));
```

The advantage of macros is that you can use them as compile-time constants in a wider range of tools, while older tools might not support `let` as a compile-time constant (or at all). Example:

```
max = `max3(10, 2, 3); // Result: max = 10
```

OR

```
max = max3(10, 2, 3); // Result: max = 10
```

Comment: You can certainly use `let` as a compile time constant expression. It may be that older tools do not support it.

Comment: @dave_59 You are correct, I had tested it on VCS 2014.10 (edaplayground's VCS version) and it failed to compile; but it does work on newer tools. Will amend answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hello, I found the $bits() method very interesting, however I don't understand it fully. Afaik, adding two 8 bit numbers for example, yields 9bits as an output. I have tested this method with Xilinx simulator, I declared a bunch of 32 bit logics, and the $bits(a + b + c + .....) always returns 32
I'd just like to understand how come that is the behavior, as it makes little sense to me. $bits() seems to be great for this application (getting max size among operands) but it certainly does not return the size needed to hold that expression, right?

Comment: @viterbi `$bits()` just returns the width of the expression in its argument, so something like `logic [31:0] x; $bits(x)` returns 32. In SystemVerilog, athematic operators arent that smart; they do not try to grow to fix that maximum possible value resulting from the equation but are just as wide as the widest component(s) (for example `logic [31:0] x, y; x+y` is not done in 33 bits but in 32 bits); see Table 11-21 in LRM 1800-2012 (it might be different number in newer/older versions).

Comment: So, using `$bits(x + y + z + ...)` works because it uses the fact the language widens the expression's width to the largest width of `x`, `y`, `z`, ... . If you want to make sure you can do math with no overflow given the full range of inputs for each variable in the equations, you will need to widen the expression yourself (Im not sure I have another good solution): `logic [31:0] x, y; {x[31], x} + {y[31], y}` (for sign extended; just append `1'b0` for unsigned)